# How can I check if vars are equal 0?

Tags: php

On php documentation we can see:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
```

If I have for example `$var1 = 0;` and `$var2 = 0;` on php I can do:

```
if (empty($var1)){
echo "empty";
}
```

But I cant do this:

```
if (empty($var1 && $var2)){
echo "empty";
}
```

How can I do for check if the two vars are equal to 0 on the same `if`?

Comment: Will $var1 and $var2 always be integers?

Comment: `empty` isn't checking for `0` it is checking for 5 values. You could do `==` or add both values, `(($var1 + $var2)  == 0)`.

Comment: @user3783243 Adding the two together isn't really a good idea, consider `$var1=-4` and `$var2=4`.

Comment: @DE_ my question is solved yet, thanks for try to help

Comment: @user3783243 thanks f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
if( $var1 === 0 && $var2 === 0 ) {
   // both empty
}
```

to see if those two variable are both holding the integer zero.

If you want a more loose type check (see if the variables are zero, or false, or null, for example), you can do:

```
if( empty($var1) && empty($var2) ) {
   // both empty
}
```

If (based on your question) you wanted to see if the variable holds the string `"0"`, you would do it like this:

```
if( $var1 === "0" && $var2 === "0" ) {
   // both are the string "0"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if($var1==="0" &&  $var2==="0"){
  echo"empty";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.